# How to indicate current open file in vimrc?

Tags: vim

I want to call Astyle in my Gvim (under Windows) to format .c .h file. I put the Astyle.exe here below:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim73
```

And it was added to the `Path` environment already.

And then I add below command in my _vimrc:

```
nmap <F10> :!Astyle --style=linux <CR>
```

But when I open a .c file and press F10, it gives some wrong message. I guess that is because Astyle does not know which file to operate. So my question is how to indicate Astyle the file to be operated?

```
nmap <F10> :!Astyle --style=linux some_indicator<CR>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

does this help?

```
:!Astyle --style=linux %:p<CR>
```